# Could T.S. Eliot's namedrop early on in Catch-22 be a play on The Wasteland

Tags: t-s-eliot, joseph-heller, catch-22, the-waste-land

Both pieces of work are reactions to post-war trauma, but unlike The Wasteland, which aims to put back together the fragments of Western Literature, fractured by The Great War, and sees the grand narrative ultimately as redeemable/salvageable, Catch-22 seems to almost be mocking Eliot by shrouding his name in a cultural amnesia, paralleling themes of disillusionment and rejection of modernism present in postmodernism.

From Chapter 4:

> 'T. S. Eliot,' ex-P.F.C. Wintergreen said in his mail-sorting cubicle at Twenty-seventh
>   Air Force Headquarters, and slammed down the telephone without
>    identifying himself.
>   Colonel Cargill, in Rome, was perplexed.
>   'Who was it?' asked General Peckem.
>   'I don't know,' Colonel Cargill replied.
>   'What did he want?'
>   'I don't know.'
>   'Well, what did he say?'
>   '"T. S. Eliot",' Colonel Cargill informed him.
>   'What's that?'
>   '"T. S. Eliot",' Colonel Cargill repeated.
>   'Just "T. S. -"'
>   'Yes, sir. That's all he said. Just "T. S. Eliot."'
>   'I wonder what it means,' General Peckem reflected. Colonel Cargill wondered,    too.
>   'T. S. Eliot,' General Peckem mused.
>   'T. S. Eliot,' Colonel Cargill echoed with the same funereal puzzlement.

For further context, this question has answers that seem to fit my question as well:
[What's the significance of the T. S. Eliot reference in Catch-22?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/3632/whats-the-significance-of-the-t-s-eliot-reference-in-catch-22)

Comment: Could you include a quote of the passage in *Catch-22* which drops Eliot's name?

Comment: I've added the passage; also I believe the correct term to be 'name-dropping', whether an ironic or sincere kind.

Comment: The run up to this is a rhetorical question, to which the answer is 'T.S. Eliot'